# Servlet Unavailable (I know it's common)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Ok, so I have my project, and all of my servlets are properly mapped (I suppose), the weird thing, is that I have my login servlet available, but once I login all of the other servlets aren't found. Currently I'm using just four servlets. here's my XML file.

```
<servlet>
    <description>Performs a login to the system.</description>
    <servlet-name>LoginUserCheck</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.LoginUserCheck</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>Updates the given order.</description>
    <display-name>OrderUpdate</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OrderUpdate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.OrderUpdate</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>Process the creation of an order.</description>
    <display-name>OrderCreate</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OrderCreate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.OrderCreate</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>Searches or Filters orders.</description>
    <display-name>OrderSearch</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OrderSearch</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.OrderSearch</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginUserCheck</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginUserCheck</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderUpdate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderUpdate</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderCreate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderCreate</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderSearch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderSearch</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref>
    <description>Database Resource.</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dbre</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Now, my servlets are contained in a package named "controllers",  it has all four of them, my context.xml file is as follows:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/RHTUBSDB" >
```

And the way I call the in the forms is like this action="controllername", with no backslash or anything.

As I said the weird thing is that only the LoginUserCheck controller is working, the others say: "servlet xxx is currently unavailable".

By the way, I wasn't sure of in which stackoverflow or exchange to post..sorry..

Comment: At first glance the configuration looks good.  Can you access the servlets by plain URL at all, or do you get the same error?

Comment: same error, I've tried al sorts of url patterns and in the tomcat "conf\web.xml" I have

Comment: <context><WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource></context>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in the server or application's logs to see if there are errors?

Sounds like the servlets could be "currently unavailable" because the application is actually throwing `HTTP 500` errors due to a problem with your code/deployment/setup.

Need to dig deeper than the friendly error messages intended for the end-user.

Comment: What do you mean, by "code/deployment/setup"?, the servlet classes, I'm thinking it might be somthing related to servlet context, but I haven't coded any of that

Comment: @Triztian - HAVE you looked at the log files??  If not, then you SHOULD.

Comment: I have, it appears to be throwing the following:
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controllers.OrderUpdate", but my classes are all there, in the 'controllers' package.

Comment: Are the classes in the correct folder for the type of project you're doing? (i.e. in WEB-INF/classes)? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Ok figured out the problem, whenever I deploy it or start to debug it (using netbeans BTW) NB removes the RHTUBSBD directory from the webapp folder in tomcat's home folder and doesn't re-deploy it, so y have to manually deploy the .war file in the webapp folder, any solution to this?